# Correct way to use -c param for php in crontab

Tags: php, linux, terminal, cron, console

I wonder if it will work and it is possible to do as follows:

```
0 3 * * * /usr/local/php5.6/bin/php -c /path/to/php/ini/php5.6.ini /path/to/script.php
```

A had to give path to php  and also the config ini because of restrictions coming from my server administrator. That's why I cannot omit the ini file where all the params are set to script.php works without problem.

Can I do as I wrote? Will it work?

Comment: does this work from command line?

Comment: The question is if it will works when I write this code to crontab file after editing by `crontab -e` command using console connection to the server.

Comment: i know. the reason I ask is it might not be working in the first place. so does it work if you execute it manually from command line?

Comment: Of course. If I run the taks from command line, not by crontab and it works perfect. But I my question I ask not why it not works but if it will work correctly. Because I have not checked on server. I only want to know if the code above is correct and will work on server when I will edit the crontab. I have been searching whole web and connot find similar param `-c` used in crontab editing.

Comment: if it works from command line by manually executing it, the above code should work. just make sure your paths are correct.

Comment: Thanks, so I try it in near future. I asked this question because I cannot find any example of using `-c` param and its value (path to ini config) to php path in crontab. So I did not know if it is possible. So as you said that syntax is correct then I will sleep a bit better, thanks again.